# Apache mod_rewrite: differences between ^([A-Za-z\/]+)$ and ^(.*)$

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I really don't understand why my .htaccess file works wrong with `^(.*)$` ...
This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

I simply want to put all the text after my host address in the GET parameter named "alias".
The result of this, is that in my PHP script "index.php", `$_GET['alias']` will have the value "index.php" instead what is after my host address.
If I change my .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z\/]+)$ index.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

I'll finally have `$_GET['alias']` with the right value.
For example if I request http://myaddress.com/the-value-of-alias, in the first case I'll get `$_GET['alias'] = 'index.php'`. In the second case instead, I'll `get $_GET['alias'] = 'the-value-of-alias'`.
Then could someone explain me what are the differences between `^([A-Za-z\/]+)$` and `^(.*)$` please?
Thank you very much in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put .*  it matches any url so you end up in a recursive redirection whereas when you have specific regular expression elements it will work as it matches your first url only. It does not match the destination url as it has a 'equal-to' symbol in it

Answer (score 0):

The `^(.*)$` expression means anything but a dot.

As for the expression  `^([A-Za-z\/]+)$` it will get the Characters from A to Z as well as a to z